# how to reverse back of mysql_escape_string function in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing

```
[{
    "id": "a34da9b020ec86dc5a7832620082ed5d",
    "type": "img",
    "name": "1458561170282.jpg",
    "mime_type": "image/jpg",
    "path": "http://images.website.com/boxdata/asset22756/images/1458561170282.jpg?r=160321075523",
    "thumb": "http://images.website.com/boxdata/asset22756/images/thumb__1458561170282.jpg?r=160321075523",
    "short_link": "http://website.com/img1084109"
}]
```

in a MySQL database using `mysql_escape_string` function.

When I retrieve the data I have the following output:

```
[\n  {\n    \"short_link\" : \"http:\\\\/\\\\/website.com\\\\/img1085805\",\n    \"id\" : \"ca96c55e1aa76fbca17ee08cad7e5a15\",\n    \"thumb\" : \"http:\\\\/\\\\/images.website.com\\\\/boxdata\\\\/asset22114\\\\/images\\\\/thumb__chat_files_41.jpg?r=160421015318\",\n    \"type\" : \"img\",\n    \"path\" : \"http:\\\\/\\\\/images.website.com\\\\/boxdata\\\\/asset22114\\\\/images\\\\/chat_files_41.jpg?r=160421015318\",\n    \"name\" : \"chat_files_41.jpg\",\n    \"mime_type\" : \"image\\\\/jpg\"\n  }\n]
```

How can I convert my data back in the initial format?

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: `var_dump(stripslashes(str_replace('\\n', "\n", $data)));`.... and don't double escape in future

Comment: If your output is still escaped then it's because your input has been double escaped. You've not shown us any of your code. So we can't say what the error is. Assuming this is the case, the remedy is simple, load the data back into PHP then write it to MySQL without another escaping cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$str='[\n {\n "short_link" : "http:\/\/website.com\/img1085805",
\n "id" : "ca96c55e1aa76fbca17ee08cad7e5a15",
\n "thumb" : "http:\/\/images.website.com\/boxdata\/asset22114\/images\/thumb__chat_files_41.jpg?r=160421015318",
\n "type" : "img",\n "path" : "http:\/\/images.website.com\/boxdata\/asset22114\/images\/chat_files_41.jpg?r=160421015318",
\n "name" : "chat_files_41.jpg",\n "mime_type" : "image\/jpg"\n }\n]';
echo stripslashes(str_replace('\n','',$str));
```

check screenshot
[image]

Comment: @Ashok Gujjar: check

Comment: what if i store just string like "Hello my A\c no is 123"?

Comment: use "Hello my A/c no is 123" otherwise stripslashes removes all backward slashes

Comment: I can not get "hello\hi how are you" as it was saved using this solution.

Comment: "hello/hi how r u"

Answer (score 0):

Use `stripslashes` function to remove slashes.

`$string = stripslashes($escaped_string);`

Comment: Is that all the escape_string does, add slashes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$correctString = nl2br(stripslashes($result));
```

By the way, you should use

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection ,$source )
```

instead of  mysql_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable (my_json_col) VALUES (:json_string)';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute([':json_string' => '[{
  "id": "a34da9b020ec86dc5a7832620082ed5d",
  "type": "img",
  "name": "1458561170282.jpg",
  "mime_type": "image/jpg",
  "path": "http://images.website.com/boxdata/asset22756/images/1458561170282.jpg?r=160321075523",
  "thumb": "http://images.website.com/boxdata/asset22756/images/thumb__1458561170282.jpg?r=160321075523",
  "short_link": "http://website.com/img1084109"}]']);
// retrieve with fetch*
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=:my_id';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute([':my_id' => 1]); //my_id is the DB row id you want
$sth->fetchObject(); //this will give you a stdClass object with row names as properties
?>
```